# How to Store Image in Firebase

Tags: database, image, firebase, upload, store

I am trying to store a test image in Firebase Storage but it is not appearing and I think the problem is with my completion handler in viewDidLoad but I am not sure how to fix it. Should it be "photoHelper" or something else? Below I have included "MyProfileViewController" that handles imagePicker and two service functions "create image" and "upload image."

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

 class MyProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var profileButton: UIButton!

let photoHelper = MGPhotoHelper()

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    profileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * profileButton.bounds.size.width
    profileButton.clipsToBounds = true

    photoHelper.completionHandler = { image in
        ProfileService.createImage(for: image)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera))
    {
        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Use Camera", style: .default) { (action) in

            let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)

            if (status == .authorized){
                self.DisplayPicker(type: .camera)
            }
            if (status == .restricted){
                self.HandleRestricted()
            }
            if (status == .denied){
                self.HandleDenied()
            }
            if (status == .notDetermined){
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video, completionHandler: { (granted) in
                    if (granted){
                        self.DisplayPicker(type: .camera)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
         alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    }

    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)) {
        let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Use Photo Library", style: .default) { (action) in

            let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

            if (status == .authorized){
                self.DisplayPicker(type: .photoLibrary)
            }
            if (status == .restricted){
                self.HandleRestricted()
            }
            if (status == .denied){
                self.HandleDenied()
            }
            if (status == .notDetermined){
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status) in
                    if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized){
                        self.DisplayPicker(type: .photoLibrary)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.profileButton
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.profileButton.bounds

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func HandleDenied(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Media Access Denied", message: "CameraTutorial does not access to your device's media. Please update your settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default){ (action) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)! as URL)
        }
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.profileButton
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.profileButton.bounds

    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func HandleRestricted(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Media Access Denied", message: "This device is restricited from accessing any media at this time", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.profileButton
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.profileButton.bounds

    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func DisplayPicker(type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: type)!
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = type
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
    profileButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    profileButton.setImage(chosenImage, for: .normal)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Create image function

```
static func createImage(for image: UIImage) {
    let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("test_image.jpg")
    StorageService.uploadImage(image, at: imageRef) { (downloadURL) in
        guard let downloadURL = downloadURL else {
            return
        }

        let urlString = downloadURL.absoluteString
        print("image url: \(urlString)")
    }
}
```

Upload image function

```
static func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, at reference: StorageReference, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    // 1
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) else {
        return completion(nil)
    }

    // 2
    reference.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        // 3
        if let error = error {
            assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            return completion(nil)
        }

        // 4
        reference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                return completion(nil)
            }
            completion(url)
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First enable rules, if you haven't.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Code for uploading and image to firebase storage.

```
private void uploadImage() {

if(filePath != null)
 {
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
progressDialog.show();

StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
ref.putFile(filePath)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        })
        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                    .getTotalByteCount());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
          }
        });
 }
```

Here Filepath is Uri of image.Hope it helps.